# Regular Expression to read between HTML works in RegEx tester but not in my code

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, raspberry-pi, weather-api

I'm fairly new to RegEx (and Python) in general and am trying to use it to read the temperature and description of weather via the HTML tags of a website.

I've attempted to rework examples of what I've been shown in class and read online to do this.

```
url = 'https://weather.com/en-AU/weather/today/l/-27.47,153.02'
contents = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode("utf-8")

start_of_div = contents.find('<div class="today_nowcard-phrase">') # start of phrase line
end_of_div = start_of_div + contents[start_of_div:].find("</div>") + 6 # close of phrase line

phrase_area = contents[start_of_div:end_of_div]
print(phrase_area)

phrase = phrase_area.rfind(r'>(.*)<') # regex tester says this works
print(phrase)
```

There's then another section that gets the degrees which uses the same kind of layout. 
It should print a phrase like 'Sunny' or 'Light Rain' or whatever else the weather is, as well as the current degrees (celsius). Instead it prints out:

```
<div class="today_nowcard-phrase">Sunny</div>
- 1
<div class="today_nowcard-temp"><span class="">21<sup>
- 1
```

Instead of -1 it should be 'Sunny' and '21' (at that point of time). The RegEx works when I put it into RegEx testing sites, but not in my actual program (probably because of some obvious error I can't see). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `str.find` doesn't implement regex, it just looks for the literal string. Have a look at the `re` module from the standard library for a Perl-like regex implementation.

Comment: `rfind()` does not use regular expressions.  Your code is looking for the literal string `>(.*)<`, which of course is not present.

Comment: Please don't use RegEx for parsing HTML. Try [html.parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html) for Python

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments used an html parser. The elements all have nice distinctive class names you can use e.g. .today_nowcard-temp (where the leading `.` is a css class selector to match on element class name)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://weather.com/en-AU/weather/today/l/-27.47,153.02')
soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')
temp = soup.select_one('.today_nowcard-temp').text
desc = soup.select_one('.today_nowcard-phrase').text
print(temp, desc)
```